# Open jupyter notebook in a text editor

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to open a jupyter notebook in a text editor like sublime or atom, so that I can quickly edit some changes and then save back?

I could not find anything related to it. Are there any extensions that open it?

Answer (score 4):

As of late 2018, there's a good solution for this, namely the [Jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) extension.  It converts your notebook to and from plain text representations that can be edited conveniently without the web app.  For example, a Python notebook by default converts to an ordinary Python script.  When converting back, the input cells of the original notebook are exactly reproduced, with the assumption that the outputs can be regenerated.

The plain text form is sometimes more convenient than the original notebook format, such as for refactoring and tracking in version control.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, Jupyter notebook, are just plain JSON files. If you do a change that does not make the JSON invalid, then it should just work; (your notebook will just be marked as untrusted on your machine), until you re-run all the code.

There is no particular plugin you need for that.